# Unable to set TestCase description with XML tags using Rally ALM API

Tags: java, gson, rally

I'm using the Rally ALM Java [SDK](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava) to create test cases programmatically. The JSON object that I create has XML tags as the test case description string.

```
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "Description": "Should process <MyTag name=\"abc\">XYZ</MyTag>",
    "TestFolder": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testfolder/123",
    "Type": "Functional",
    "Method": "Automated",
    "Priority": "Useful",
    "Owner": "X",
    "Project": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/456"
}
```

Now inside Rally SDK code where GSON builder (which has `escapeHtmlChars` property set as `true`) creates a String representation of this object changes it to:

```
{
    "TestCase": {
        "Name": "Test",
        "Description": "Should process \u003cMyTag name\u003d\"abc\"\u003eXYZ\u003c/MyTag\u003e",
        "TestFolder": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testfolder/A",
        "Type": "Functional",
        "Method": "Automated",
        "Priority": "Useful",
        "Owner": "X",
        "Project": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/B"
    }
}
```

And finally when the request gets processed the custom tags are not present in the test case description. It's just `Should process XYZ`. Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve the issue with XML escape characters, there is an Apache util (`commons-text`) that helped to achieve this: `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(xmlString)`.